# Is this a demonstration or a definition?

Tags: factorial

Some people says that this can be demonstrated $0!=1$, but other say that this is a definition. Which one is correct?

Let's given $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$(n+1)!=(n+1)\cdot n!$$
$$(0+1)!=(0+1)\cdot 0!$$
$$1!=1\cdot 0!$$
$$1=0!$$

Comment: It depends. What is the definition of factorial?

Comment: It's asumed that the definition is $(n+1)!=n!\cdot (n+1)$.

Comment: $(n+1)!=n!\cdot (n+1)$ is not enough, as you have to start somewhere. For example you could have $f(n+1)=f(n)\cdot  (n+1)$ and $f(3)=42$, from which you could demonstrate $f(5)=840$ and $f(0)=7$.  If you start with $0!=1$ then it is in the definition; if you start at $1!=1$ then $0!=\frac{1!}1=1$ is a demonstration.

Comment: A proper definition of a function $f\colon A\to B$ should start by specifying $A$ (and $B$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen OP implicitly defines
$$n! := \begin{cases} n(n-1)! & n > 1\\ 1& n=1\end{cases}$$
with domain $\mathbb N$ as said ($0\notin\mathrm{dom}(!)$ here)

Comment: @AlexR If $0 \not \in \mathrm{dom}(!)$ then it doesn't make sense to define $0!$ - clearly the OP wants to include zero in the domain of the factorial function... so I don't see how he "implicitly defines" it that way unless he is schizophrenic ;)

Comment: @Thomas $0\notin\mathbb N$ for me, so the recurrence is only allowed for $n>0$ and he uses $1!=1\cdot 0!$ to conclude $1=0!$ wich can only be said if $1! = 1$ is defined. That's where I see the implicitly used definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the equations suitable to define $n!$, there are multiple possible answers:

If $n! := n (n-1)!, 0!=1$ is used, it's a plain **definition**.
If $1! = 1$ is used as the starting point, it can be proved that $0!:=1$ is a **consistent extension**. (this is what you did)
If $n! := \prod_{i\in \mathbb N, i \le n} i$, it follows from the **definition of the empty product**, $\prod_{k\in\emptyset} f(k) := 1$.
If $n! := \Gamma(n+1), n\in\mathbb N$, it **follows from** the **definition** because $\Gamma(1) = 1$.
If $n! := |S_n| = |\{f: A\to A \text{ bijective}\}|$ with $|A| = n$, there is only one set with $0$ elements, $\emptyset$ and **only one function** $f: \emptyset \to\emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple equivalent ways of defining the factorial function.  Since the exact choice of definition doesn't matter in the long run, people don't generally make a big deal about which definition they're choosing.  In some contexts, this would be a definition, whereas in others it would be a proof from the definition.

Comment: The questions changes then... which are the definitions taken to make this a demonstration?

Comment: @hkviktor There are many ways to do that. If you accept $\prod_\emptyset = 1$ I listed four variations where $0!$ is not directly defined; if you consider $\prod_\emptyset = 1$ part of the definition, there are still three examples remaining.

Answer (score 0):

In demonstrating that $0! = 1$, you assumed that $1! = 1$.

If you define $n!$ by

1. $1! = 1$
2. $n! = n(n - 1)!$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

with $\mathbb{N}$ defined as the set of positive integers, then you can demonstrate that $0! = 1$ by substituting $1$ for $n$.

If, as some mathematicians do, you define $\mathbb{N}$ to be the set of non-negative integers, it would make sense to define $n!$ by

1. $0! = 1$
2. $(n + 1)! = (n + 1)n!$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, with $n \geq 1$

Comment: Actually, if you use your first definition to define the factorial function for $n\in\mathbb N$, then $0!$ is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I will revise.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of showing why this should be true:
\begin{align}
5!&=5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot(1)\\
4!&=4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot(1)\\
3!&=3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot(1)\\
2!&=2\cdot1\cdot(1)\\
1!&=1\cdot(1)\\
0!&=(1)
\end{align}
The first five lines are easy to verify, and the last line follows by analogy.

Comment: Could we not append another multiplication by one to the right of each line, and conclude that $(-1)!=1$ by this reasoning?

Comment: @Peter Um... good point. I suppose we could say that we _only delete from the numbers counting down from $n$ to $1$_... but now it's getting arbitrary. I don't know.

Comment: I think a possibly better way to see why it *should* be true, is that when you divide $n!$ by $n$, you get $(n-1)!$. So we would expect $0!=1!/1$. This also gives us $(-1)!$ as being infinite, which is consistent with the gamma function. However it is essentially the same reasoning as the OP.

Comment: @Peter Yeah, I was trying to be a bit original... I slightly edited my post, but I doubt it really changes anything.